# NgClass not choosing the correct class

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have an object, which store a Boolean value.
When I display the other value of this object, I'd like to apply a different style depending on that Boolean value.

I tried about a dozen of combination : *ngClass, [(ngClass)], class.myNewClass...

```
<td [ngClass]="(theBoolean ? 'classActivated' : 'classDeacticated' )">...</td>

<td [class.classActivated]="theBoolean" [class.classDeacticated]="!theBoolean" >...</td>
```

Both of those doesn't work for example. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
They are contained in a tr, which contain a *ngFor, itself in a table with another *ngFor (as I'm displaying a table of objects, with contain one attribute that is a table too).

**EDIT2:**
I obtain those value from a service, which is an `Observable<myObject[]>`. All the value are properly displayed in the page, as well as the Boolean value which I'm displaying on the web page for debugging.

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the current behavior? What are the possible values of `theBoolean`?

Comment: Think you have to look into `<td *ngIf="theBoolean">` and else.

Comment: Expected result : "I'd like to apply a different style depending on that boolean value."
Current behavior, it is only displaying one case. 
As for the possible values of `theBoolean` , well, `true` or `false`. Where you expecting something else ?

Comment: @Swoox why would he need ngIf to add/remove classes? With ngIf only elements can be added removed.

Comment: `true` or `false` - it could be null (or any other value that you expect to be coerced to a boolean value)

Comment: Well as I am displaying their value, they are always set to either `true` or `false`

Comment: Depending on when you initialize it, your boolean might be `null` at some point, even if you don't see it.

Comment: @Mozgor when I print the value on the page, it show true or false. Shouldn't `null` be considered false anyway in a ternary ?

Comment: You're probably right, however I already experienced unexpected behavior when binding template condition to boolean I would initialize a bit late.

Comment: @user96649 any chance to see your html or a simplified sample ?

Comment: Something wrong with the class names or class properties in the css? Do you have .classActivated or .classDeacticated is the stylesheet?

Comment: @Vega, both class work if I hard code one of them to the <td>. Mozgor I'll see if I can give more information

Comment: How did you declare theBoolean?

Comment: It is included in the array of object I obtain from my service. Each of those object that are displayed already have it assigned to true or false.

Answer (score 4):

Both your cases should work. Here is a simple [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/qI0PiuK31Ou5MdH3A4vb/) with an example. Something is wrong outside of the provided piece of code. Try to reproduce your error in Plunkr or show us the whole component.

Answer (score 1):

Another working syntax would be, according to [this](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) :

```
<td [ngClass]="{'classActivated': theBoolean, 'classDeacticated': !theBoolean}">...</td>
```

Comment: I tried this before, retried it, but still doesn't work. I'll add more detail to my question.

Comment: Can you tell / show us when / where / how do you initialize / update `theBoolean` value ?

Comment: Got it. When you try this syntax, what does happen ? Only first class is bound, and the second never shows up even when `theBoolean` switches value ?

If so, did you try to initialize manually `theBoolean` to false ? Just to see if before getting your Observable value , `classDeacticated` is bound.

Anyway I would suggest you to look for binding problems : it's looking like your template doesn't give a clue about `theBoolean` getting updated

Answer (score 0):

The error might be the omitting of the object/array element name. If you are making an iteration over an array (obtained or not from a service) and theBoolean is a property of that array/object, then you should specify it in the template syntax, as so:

```
<td [class.classActivated]="objectName.theBoolean" [class.classDeacticated]="!objectName.theBoolean" >...</td>
```

or

```
<td [ngClass]="{'classActivated': item.theBoolean, 'classDeacticated': !item.theBoolean}">...</td>
```

were objectName / item are the holders of theBoolean property.

Comment: Have you found the source of the issue?